# What brand name faucet does this logo belong to?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I am trying to replace the ceramic disc stem cartridge for this faucet.

Can anyone name who this logo belong to?

[image: faucet]

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: I am in the USA